# Why doesn't Solidity throw an error for overflows?

Tags: solidity, integers

It seems like there are going to be a lot of people that forget to check for integer overflows in Solidity.

I am wondering if there is a reason why Solidity doesn't throw errors for integer overflows like Python or most other programming languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that Shawn Tabrizi posted may provide the reason why Solidity itself doesn't throw errors for integer overflow. However, there are helpful developer tools that can help mitigate these errors. When deploying a contract I'll usually upload my abi to Amberdata.io which runs automated security audits. For instance, with the [0x Protocol contract](https://amberdata.io/addresses/0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498/management?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=link) it shows some integer overflows in their code.

Hope that help!

Comment: thank you! Yes, that link is helpful in checking to make sure the contract is good.  Will use it!